# Google directions api return zero results for some Addresses

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, directions, google-directions-api

I have studied all previous questions but did not found solution. I'm working on Google Directions API,to draw route in android. I am getting addresses from Google Places and it draws a route but there are many places where Directions returns no result.While I have checked google map and some other apps they render the same address.Then I tried the simple query in browser but the problem remains same.Help me please I am stucked here, I will be very thankful to you.Origin address is problamatic
Here is my query

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=University%20of%20gujrat,gujrat,punjab,pakistan&destination=gujranwala,punjab,pakistan&key=
```

And the example address is "University of Gujrat, Gujrat, Punjab,Pakistan"
I am attaching browser output. Thanks in advance.

[browser output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WjP6f.png)

Comment: I get a full response.  Click on this link:  https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=University%20of%20gujrat,gujrat,punjab,pakistan&destination=gujranwala,punjab,pakistan

Answer (score 2):

I actually tried your given query and it returned a `"status" : "OK"`.

However, for some addresses that you got `zer0_results`, as discussed in [Directions Response Elements](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#DirectionsResponseElements), the following are the indications of values in the `status` field within the Directions response:

- `NOT_FOUND` indicates at least one of the locations specified in the request's origin, destination, or waypoints could not be geocoded.
- `ZERO_RESULTS` indicates no route could be found between the origin and destination.

To avoid these error codes, please check parameter values that you have entered in your HTTPS Directions requests. As standard in URLs, all parameters are separated using the ampersand (&) character. The list of parameters and their possible values are enumerated in [Request Parameters](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#RequestParameters).

Comment: thanks for your answer, I got the solution, the problem was that i was sending direct addresses without way points. Now i converted it into lat-lang and it worked for me.